# Format function error with percentage data

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute below script in MS SQL Server 2016, I got the result with 'y'. Why 137% < 20% ? But If I change it to under 100%, it seems work fine.

```
select IIF(FORMAT(1.37,'P0') < FORMAT(0.2,'P0'), 'y', 'n')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing strings, and string comparisons are not numbers.  Strings are compared alphabetically and '1' < '2', so '1000' < '2', in the same way that 'azzzz' < 'b'.

Instead, just compare numbers and use the ANSI standard `case`:

```
select (case when 1.37 < 0.2 then 'y' else 'n' end)
```

Only use `iif()` if you are using a "database", such as MS Access, that does not support the `case` expression.  `case` is the standard in SQL for conditional functionality; `iif()` is for backwards support to MS Access.

Comment: Can I ask why iif() is not recommended?

Comment: I suppose one can argue that CASE is more portable which makes it "better", but from a purely sql server POV there is no particular reason to favor one over the other in simple logic like this. Internally IIF is converted to [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql). Since IIF is relatively new, you will find CASE more common.